# Trying to create simple trigger on Supabase/PosgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, supabase

Very very new here and to PGSQL creating an app using flutterflow. I am trying to create a trigger function that will update a column `holes` when a new row is added to the `scorecard` table using a subquery of another table called `courses`.

I could be doing this completely wrong but any ideas would be appreciated, the function I created is as below:

```
create or replace function holes2()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
  Update scorecards
  SET holes=
  (Select holes from courses
  Where courses.name=scorecards.course_name);
  return new;
end;
$$;
```

The trigger I created to call this is this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER scorecards2
AFTER UPDATE ON scorecards
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE holes2();
```

At the moment it is creating the row in the supabase table but it is not triggering the function to update the holes field. I have tried this as a before and after update but I cannot seem to get this to work.

As I said above, any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: 1) Read [plpgsql trigger functions.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). 2) Are you trying to change the value of the `holes` column for the row you are inserting? 3) Is `Select holes from courses  Where courses.name=scorecards.course_name` going to return more then one value? Add answers to above a **text update** to question.

Comment: I am trying to change the holes column for the row I am inserting as I am unable to populate this in flutterflow before I create the row. That would return more than one row, I ideally would only like to update the inserted row. I am very new to this and feel like I am just missing something obvious!

Comment: Read the link I posted earlier it explains a lot. See my 'answer' below.

Comment: I have read this and I have created the function and the trigger but no success, if I run the query itself outside of the function/trigger this works perfectly, so I must have something wrong still! The row gets inserted but the holes field does not get updates leading me to think the trigger must not be firing. I am using supabase, is there anything else I would need to consider to ge tthis working or any other information I could give you all to help? Thanks you again

Comment: Reviewing this the ID number is still incrementing, so its as if its inserting the line, deleting the line, but then failing to insert the updated line

Comment: 1) See my modified answer. I did not pay sufficient attention to your `CREATE TRIGGER` statement. That should be a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, they can modify the row before it is inserted. An `AFTER * ` trigger happens after the INSERT/UPDATE and cannot modify the row. 2) Add the actual INSERT you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A semi-answer, as it outlines what I think you want to achieve.:

```
create or replace function holes2()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
  NEW.holes = (Select holes from courses
  Where courses.name=NEW.course_name LIMIT 1);
 
  return new;
  
end;
$$;

--UPDATE to answer

CREATE TRIGGER scorecards2
BEFORE INSERT ON scorecards
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE holes2();
```

Note the `LIMIT 1` in the query. You can only use one value. So either use a `LIMIT` or construct a query you know only returns one value.

Answer (score 0):

First your trigger should be `AFTER INSERT` trigger, because you want to update column after new row is inserted.

> Create a trigger function that will update a column `holes` when a new row is added to the scorecard table

Also, use `NEW` keyword for referring to the new row:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION holes2()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE scorecards
  SET holes = (
    SELECT holes
    FROM courses
    WHERE courses.name = NEW.course_name
  );
  RETURN NEW;
END;

$$;
```

Now, create a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER scorecards2
AFTER INSERT ON scorecards
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE holes2();
```

More [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-triggers/creating-first-trigger-postgresql/).

I have not tested it, its based on my previous knowledge.